# When importing Nim module for Lua bindings, error shows: "could not load: lua(|5.1|5.0).dll"

Tags: dll, lua, nim-lang

I'm new to the Nim programming language, and coming from a Lua background, it excited me to find out that there is a module for adding Lua bindings to Nim.

I installed Nimble (Nim's package manager) for Windows and executed "nimble install lua" to download and install the correct module. Upon trying to import it and compile the source, this happened:

```
C:\Users\Ashley\Desktop\Stuff\Coding\Nim\Projects\LuaTest>nim c -r "C:\Users\Ashley\Desktop\Stuff\Coding\Nim\Projects\LuaTest\main.nim"
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: main [Processing]
Hint: lua [Processing]
CC: main
CC: lua_lua
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: operation successful (10698 lines compiled; 1.262 sec total; 16.163MB; Debug Build) [SuccessX]
could not load: lua(|5.1|5.0).dll
Error: execution of an external program failed: 'c:\users\ashley\desktop\stuff\coding\nim\projects\luatest\main.exe '
```

I have Lua 5.1 already installed with the proper entries in PATH. It's located in Program Files (x86). The directory contains a dll called lua5.1.dll. I tried looking up the error on Google, but there were no results that helped. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try putting the dll in same dir as the project: `C:\Users\Ashley\Desktop\Stuff\Coding\Nim\Projects\LuaTest`

Comment: @hjpotter92 The same issue happens

Comment: And if you put it in the directory where nim was installed

Comment: @hjpotter92 Nope, I tried C:\Nim and C:\Nim\bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you can put the library at the same place as the generated binary. In this case the file should be called `lua.dll`, `lua5.1.dll` or `lua5.0.dll`. Also make sure that the library and binary are both for the same system architecture, either x86 (32bit) or x86-64 (64bit).

Comment: This didn't work. You might be onto something though, because my Lua installation is 32bit and my Nim compiler is 64bit. To fix that, I compiled with the "--cpu:i386" flag, but the same error happened with the result.

Comment: I downloaded the Lua 5.1 64bit binary and it worked. Thanks for the help!